# Cross-browser animation antialiasing

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to animate a small bar that widens slightly and loops back. The animation involve it widening from 4px to 8px and back. In Chrome, this animation is antialiased, but in Firefox and IE it isn't. I sort-of got it working in Firefox by giving the element a 1px border of the background colour, but that doesn't work in IE and messes with Chrome.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qAGL8/

```
@keyframes myAnimation {
    0%, 100% { transform: scaleX(1); }
    50% { transform: scaleX(2); }
}

.thing {
    width: 4px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    animation: myAnimation 4s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

White bar on black, this is how it antialiases in Chrome (note the grey):

[image: Antialiased Image]

Other browser just do whole pixels. So, basically, is there any way of getting this correctly antialiasing in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

if you add a transparent outline on `.thing` element, the animation is smoother even on Firefox

```
outline: 1px transparent solid;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bf99F/

Comment: That does fix Firefox without messing up Chrome but it still doesn't fix IE. :-(